# itemClickListener. How to click on item in listView?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

Activity code:

```
package com.example.tayyab.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile);

        populateListView();
    }

    private void populateListView() {

        String[] myItems = {"Missions","Messages","Camera","Gallery","Temprature","Humidity"};
        int[] img = {R.drawable.target,R.drawable.chat,R.drawable.camera,R.drawable.gallery,R.drawable.temp,R.drawable.humidity};
        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,myItems);
        //ArrayAdapter<Integer> ad = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,R.layout.list_item,img);

        final ProfileAdapter adapter = new ProfileAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_item);
        int i=0;
        for(String Name : myItems){
            Profile obj = new Profile(Name,img[i]);
            adapter.add(obj);
            i++;
        }

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setClickable(true);
        ImageButton b3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(MyProfile.this,MainMission.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Log.i("Log ","Inside Click Listener");
                String myItems = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),myItems,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(i==1) {
                    Log.i("Message Event", "Inside Message Activity");
                    Intent a = new Intent(MyProfile.this, MainMission.class);
                    startActivity(a);
                }
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Adapter Class:

```
package com.example.tayyab.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProfileAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List list = new ArrayList();

    public ProfileAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    public void add(Profile object) {
        list.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    static class ImageHolder {
        ImageView img;
        TextView txt;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        row = convertView;
        ImageHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ImageHolder();
            holder.img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.profile_images);
            holder.txt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.profile_names);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {        
            holder = (ImageHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Profile pr = (Profile) getItem(position);
        holder.img.setImageResource(pr.getImg_names());
        holder.txt.setText(pr.getItem_names());

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want get the clicked item of your list right? you need to set a onclicklistener in your row layout, and then do whatever you want,if you need to pass the clicked item to the activity you can use an interface or call a method in you activity by passing the position as the parameter

Comment: Is not clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to make listener to listen for clicks on ListView Items. What you did there is not a proper way to do so.

You need to add a onItemClickListener to your ListView

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
    { 
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item #" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

There you have a basic Listener which will tell you what item you clicked. You can do the logic then inside the `onItemClick` method.

Also, if you are using custom layout for your ListView's row, you need to add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

on the first parent layout inside the list.

Also, consider using RecyclerView instead of ListView.